# How do you use a switch statement with a nested enum?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I've created an enum for Instagram endpoints with nested enums similar to [Moya](https://github.com/terhechte/appventure-blog/blob/master/resources/posts/2015-10-17-advanced-practical-enum-examples.org#api-endpoints).

```
enum Instagram {
    enum Media {
        case Popular
        case Shortcode(id: String)
        case Search(lat: Float, lng: Float, distance: Int)
    }
    enum Users {
        case User(id: String)
        case Feed
        case Recent(id: String)
    }
}
```

I would like to return the path for each endpoint.

```
extension Instagram: TargetType {
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .Media.Shortcode(let id):
            return "/media/shortcode"
        }
    }
}
```

However I'm getting an error on the switch statement above for the `path`.

> Enum case `Shortcode` is not a member of type `Instagram`

How to fix?

[Advanced Practical Enums](https://github.com/terhechte/appventure-blog/blob/master/resources/posts/2015-10-17-advanced-practical-enum-examples.org#api-endpoints)

Comment: explain what you're trying to do

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a valid syntax. What you're looking for is a class or struct with nested enums to hold the url type that struct or class uses. As @Nick said please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe the best approach is to extend the Media enum to conform to the TargetType protocol.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I'm adding a more general answer for a few reasons.

1. This is the only open question regarding nested enums and switch statements. [The other one is sadly closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333464/best-way-to-nest-enums-for-access-by-switch-statements-in-swift#38333784).
2. The only legit answer does not show how to assign the value of a nested enum to a symbol. The syntax was not intuitive to me.
3. None of the other answers have extensive case examples.
4. An enum nested 3 levels deep is more illustrative of the required syntax. Using efremidze answer still took me a while to work it out.

```
enum Action {
    case fighter(F)
    case weapon(W)

    enum F {
        case attack(A)
        case defend(D)
        case hurt(H)

        enum A {
            case fail
            case success
        }
        enum D {
            case fail
            case success
        }
        enum H {
            case none
            case some
        }
    }
    enum W {
        case swing
        case back
    }
}

// Matches "3 deep"
let action = Action.fighter(.attack(.fail))
// Matches "1 deep" because more general case listed first.
let action2 = Action.weapon(.swing)

switch action {
case .fighter(.attack(.fail)):
    print("3 deep")
case .weapon:
    print("1 deep")
case .weapon(.swing):
    print("2 deep to case")
case .fighter(.attack):
    print("2 deep to another enum level")
default:
    print("WTF enum")
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to match along the path of the nested enums? Such as having a `case F:` match all enums nested inside of `F`? This would help to use the enums as categories rather than having to list every single case in a single switch statement.

Comment: @JasonHarrison The "1 deep" case in the `switch` statement does what you are asking. Scroll the code vertically in my answer. It does not all show at once on this page.

Comment: @jeff thanks! I missed the scroll bar! IMHO, all scrolling text areas should cut off the bottom half of the bottom line to reflect the additional text below the cut.  I'm sure that pixel misers will hate that.

Comment: How could you associate a text string with each case in this hierarchy?

Answer (score 18):

By adding an associated value for the nested enum you can access it using a switch statement.

```
enum Instagram {
    enum MediaEndpoint {
        case Search(lat: Float, lng: Float, distance: Int)
    }
    case Media(MediaEndpoint)
}

extension Instagram: TargetType {
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .Media(.Search):
            return "/media/search"
        }
    }
}

// Demo

protocol TargetType {
    var path: String { get }
}

class MoyaProvider<Target: TargetType> {
    func request(_ target: Target, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {}
}

let provider = MoyaProvider<Instagram>()
provider.request(.Media(.Search(lat: 0, lng: 0, distance: 0))) {}
```

Comment: Note that you can simplify that to `case .Media(.Search):`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835037/conditional-enum-switch-with-stored-enum.

Answer (score 4):

There is a couple of problems with your architecture. You should know when and why you need to use extensions and protocols and how you should structure your blocks of code.

1. If your type needs to conform to that protocol, feel free to use it to
   ensure you set your own standards. I don't even see that in the github project you referred to.
2. Extension are good way to have a primitive type and extend its functionality in other parts of the project. It doesn't make sense to me why you should extend the type right after declaration. A good use case of it is where the String type has been extended to support URL Encoded values:

```
private extension String {
    var URLEscapedString: String {
        return self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
    }
}
```

3. When you are using this type of switch-case block

```
switch self {
    case .Zen:
        return "/zen"
    case .UserProfile(let name):
        return "/users/\(name.URLEscapedString)"
    case .UserRepositories(let name):
        return "/users/\(name.URLEscapedString)/repos"
}
```

The value in the case should be a member of self. that's why it can not find the type. the type is declared inside Instagram enum but it doesn't hold value in the self. it holds value inside Media. So move your media related function into the declaration of Media and access them there. That way self is referring to Media. Here's the full working code for me:

```
private extension String {
    var URLEscapedString: String {
        return self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
    }
}
```

public enum Instagram {

```
public enum Media {
    case Search(String)

    var path:String {
        switch self {

        case Media.Search(let keyword):
            return "/media/search/\(keyword.URLEscapedString)"
        }
    }
}
```

}

var me = Instagram.Media.Search("me")
print(me.path)

4. As a piece of advice, in each step of building your whole architecture just question yourself if that piece of code belongs to that type or should be accessible publicly. In this case it makes complete sense to move search to Media cause you are searching media. You can add the same pattern for something like User and have search under user that returns different value.

Comment: So there is no way to use a switch statement in the form I provided above?

Comment: I don't think there is. Cause the value doesn't exist in the parent class and nor it's one of the enum states belongs to that class. The Swift documentation has a good example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Enum case Search is not a member of type Instagram

As the compiler say, `Search` is not a member of type `Instagram`. It's just an enum in the scope of `Instagram`. You have to create a member that is an instance of `Search` in `Instagram`

```
struct Instagram {
    enum Media {
        case Search(lat: Float, lng: Float, distance: Int)
    }
    // something like:
     var media = .Search(lat: 0, lng: 0, distance: 0) 
    // I'm not sure this one is right syntax
    // because I can't check it right now.
    // please just get the idea
}
extension Instagram: TargetType {
    var path: String {
        switch self.media {
        case .Search(let _, let _, let _):
            return "/media/search"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as I know you can not store any variable inside an enum. You can do it only with structures and classes. I suggested in my first comment to replace enum with structure if it's possible but if you want to keep everything as enum your solution will not work.

Comment: @MKoosej Thank you very much. I updated my answer and voted for you also. :)