# Conditional enum switch with stored enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I'd like this code to work.

I have an enum where the case Direction.Right takes a distance parameter.

```
enum Direction {
    case Up
    case Down
    case Left
    case Right(distance: Int)
}
```

Now another enum that can take a Direction parameter.

```
enum Blah {
    case Move(direction: Direction)
}

let blah = Blah.Move(direction: Direction.Right(distance: 10))
```

When I switch on the `Blah` enum I want to be able to conditionally switch on the Move.Right like this...

```
switch blah {
case .Move(let direction) where direction == .Right:
    print(direction)
default:
    print("")
}
```

But I get the error...

> > binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Direction' and '_'

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your `case .Move(let direction) where direction == .Up:` works just fine for me.

Comment: @MartinR hmm.. I get `Binary operator == cannot be applied to operands of type Direction and _` with that. May be a clean and build problem though. I'll take a look thanks.

Comment: @MartinR ah, it seems if you add a `distance` to the Direction then it goes wrong. Let me edit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is actually quite easy :)

```
    case .Move(.Up):
        print("up")
    case .Move(.Right(let distance)):
        print("right by", distance)
```

Your code

```
    case .Move(let direction) where direction == .Right:
```

does not compile because `==` is defined by default only for
enumerations *without* associated values.

Comment: Excellent. Makes perfect sense too. Was about to edit in the parameter. Thanks :D