# More concise way to nest enums for access by switch statements in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I have a nested enum like so, for describing basic relative positioning:

```
  enum Location {
    enum Top {
      case Left
      case Right
      case Center
    }
    enum Bottom {
      case Left
      case Right
      case Center
    }
    enum Left {
      case Top
      case Bottom
      case Center
    }
    enum Right {
      case Top
      case Bottom
      case Center
    }
    enum Center {
      case Center
    }
  }
```

If I try to run a `switch` statement with it, none of the enums show up as possible cases, and if I try to list them I get an error:

```
func switchOverEnum(enumCase: Location) {
  switch enumCase {
  case .Top:
    print("hey this didn't cause an error whoops no it did")
  }
}
```

The error is: `Enum case 'Top' not found in type 'Location'.`

Now there's a version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822345/how-do-you-use-a-switch-statement-with-a-nested-enum), and according to the most helpful answer, it should be done like this:

```
   enum Location {
    enum TopLocations {
      case Left
      case Right
      case Center
    }
    enum BottomLocations {
      case Left
      case Right
      case Center
    }
    enum LeftLocations {
      case Top
      case Bottom
      case Center
    }
    enum RightLocations {
      case Top
      case Bottom
      case Center
    }
    enum CenterLocations {
      case Top
      case Bottom
      case Left
      case Right
      case Center
    }
    case Top(TopLocations)
    case Bottom(BottomLocations)
    case Left(LeftLocations)
    case Right(RightLocations)
    case Center(CenterLocations)
  }
```

Which totally works, but seems a bit clunky, or inelegant, or un-Swift-like. Is this really the most concise way?

Comment: Why it is unswifty? It gives a simple thing maximum complexity. This is totally swifty.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Your original was just silly (`.Top` is _not_ a case of Location, it's a nested enum, so it's hard to imagine what you were expecting), and "best way" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as primarily opinion-based since answers can only be based on opinion and preference, not fact.  Consider posting to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) with a complete, real example.

Comment: Hey guys I'm okay with you closing it, thanks a lot for the extra explanations of why. It kind of stinks when people just vote against something and don't explain it. If y'all think it should be closed, its makes sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would be much more concisely expressed with two enums and a tuple. Try this in a playground:

```
enum HorizontalPosition {
    case Left
    case Right
    case Center
}

enum VerticalPosition {
    case Top
    case Bottom
    case Center
}

typealias Location = (horizontal: HorizontalPosition, vertical: VerticalPosition)

let aLocation = Location(horizontal: .Left, vertical: .Bottom)

switch aLocation {

case (.Left, .Bottom): print ("left bottom")
case (.Center, .Center): print ("center center")
default: print ("everything else")
}
```

Comment: Even though the question's getting closed, you should get some credit: this is a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: @LeMotJuiced thanks! I hope I was able to help